# How do I determine if the user input is odd or even?

Tags: python

I am supposed to find out if all of the 5 numbers that the user enters are odd or even. It should have an output that looks something like this:

```
>>> Enter 5 integers (e.g. 1 2 3 4 5): 1 2 3 4 5 
The array contains odd and even numbers. 

>>> Enter 5 integers (e.g. 1 2 3 4 5): 1 3 5 7 9 
The array contains only odd numbers.

>>> Enter 5 integers (e.g. 1 2 3 4 5): 2 4 6 8 0 
The array contains only even numbers.
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def main():
    numEnter = 5
    numbers = [0] * numEnter

    for index in range(numEnter):
        numbers[index] = int(input('Enter the numbers: '))
    print(numbers)

    if numbers % 2 == 0:
    print('The numbers are odd')

main()
```

I am having trouble with this code. I can't seem to figure out how to see if the numbers are odd or even.

Comment: You need to look at the individual numbers, so start by looping over them.

Answer (score 2):

```
def oddOrEven(number):
    if ( (number % 2) == 0 ):
        print('The number is even')
    else:
        print('The number is odd')


numEnter = 5
numArray = [0] * numEnter

for index in range(numEnter):
    numArray[index] = int(raw_input('Enter an integer number: '))
    oddOrEven(numArray[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
numEnter = 5
numbers = [0] * numEnter

odd = False
even = False

for index in range(numEnter):
    numbers[index] = int(input('Enter the numbers: '))
print(numbers)

for i in numbers:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even = True
        continue
    else:
        odd = True
        continue

if odd and even:
    print 'The array contains odd and even numbers.'
elif odd:
    print 'The array contains only odd numbers.'
elif even:
    print 'The array contains only even numbers'
```

If entered `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` output would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
The array contains odd and even numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you have to indent code after an if statement. Your `if numbers % 2 == 0:` isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension with some built-in functions:

```
numbers = []
numEnter = 5

for i in range(numEnter):
    numbers.append(int(input('Enter the numbers: ')))

results = [number % 2 in numbers]

if all(results):
    print('The array contains only odd numbers.')
elif any(results):
    print('The array contains odd and even numbers.')
else:
    print('The array contains only even numbers.')
```

List comprehension expression will create new list with results of modulo operation, something like this:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Python treats 1 and 0 as True and False respectively. So all() function will return true if all numbers have 1 after modulo(%) operation. any() function will return true if at least one element is 1. So if all elements is 0, it looks like all numbers are even.

This solution includes more usage of standard library functions, which has better performance.